# POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios

on submiting my login credential I am getting error as 404 not found . i have created api for login but on post req i am getting error as cannot find "/api/user/login"

## my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require('cors')

require("./config/db");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");

dotenv.config();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
```

type here

```
    res.send("hello")
})

app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening at ${port}`);
})
```

## my user routes

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require('cors')

require("./config/db");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");

dotenv.config();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello")
})

app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening at ${port}`);
})
```

## my user controller.js

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");


const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

    if (!name || !email || !password) {
        throw new Error("Please Enter all the fields");
    }

    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });
    try {


        if (userExists) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error("User already exists");
        }

        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            pic,
        });

        if (user) {
            res.status(201).json({
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                pic: user.pic,
                token: await generateToken(user._id),
            })
            console.log(user);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // else {
        res.status(400);
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to create the User");
        // }

    }
};

const authUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
        res.json({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
            pic: user.pic,
            token: generateToken(user._id),
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
};

const allUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const keyword = req.query.search ? {
        $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } },
            { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } },
        ],
    }
        : {};

    const users = await User.find(keyword).find({ _id: { $ne: req.user._id } });
    res.send(users);
}


module.exports = { registerUser, authUser, allUsers };
```

## my frontend of login.js

```
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/button";
import { FormControl, FormLabel } from "@chakra-ui/form-control";
import { Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement } from "@chakra-ui/input";
import { VStack } from "@chakra-ui/layout";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'



const Login = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setShow(!show);
    const toast = useToast();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const submitHandler = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (!email || !password) {
            toast({
                title: "Please Fill all the Feilds",
                status: "warning",
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: "bottom",
            });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                },
            };

            const { data } = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:3000/api/user/login",
                { email, password },
                config
            );

            toast({
                title: "Login Successful",
                status: "success",
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: "bottom",
            })
            localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
            setLoading(false);
            navigate("/chats");
        } catch (error) {
            toast({
                title: "Error Occured!",
                description: error.response.data.message,
                status: "error",
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: "bottom",
            });
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <VStack spacing="10px">
            <FormControl id="email" isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Email Address</FormLabel>
                <Input
                    value={email}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter Your Email Address"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id="password" isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <InputGroup size="md">
                    <Input
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        type={show ? "text" : "password"}
                        placeholder="Enter password"
                    />
                    <InputRightElement width="4.5rem">
                        <Button h="1.75rem" size="sm" onClick={handleClick}>
                            {show ? "Hide" : "Show"}
                        </Button>
                    </InputRightElement>
                </InputGroup>
            </FormControl>
            <Button
                colorScheme="blue"
                width="100%"
                style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                onClick={submitHandler}
                isLoading={loading}
            >
                Login
            </Button>
            <Button
                variant="solid"
                colorScheme="red"
                width="100%"
                onClick={() => {
                    setEmail("guest@example.com");
                    setPassword("123456");
                }}
            >
                Get Guest User Credentials
            </Button>
        </VStack>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Import `controller.js` into `userRoutes.js`.

Comment: const { registerUser, authUser, allUsers } = require('../controllers/userController'); already imported

Comment: And now, you have to use `registerUser, authUser, allUsers` variable in `userRouters.js` file.

Comment: const express = require('express');
const { registerUser, authUser, allUsers } = require('../controllers/userController');
const { protect } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware');

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser).get(protect, allUsers);

router.route("/login").post(authUser);

module.exports = router;        //already i have used

Comment: Let's update your question to provide userRouters.js content.